# how i get width and height of window on listeners extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

When i resize my window then alert width and height then again resize my window again alert width and height, how it will be please help. In extjs4

```
new Ext.Window({
     title:'my window',
     id:'mywindow',
     listeners:{
          alert("need width and height");
     }
}).show();
```

please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding 'resize' event on window

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title  : 'Hello',
    height : 200,
    width  : 400,
    layout : 'fit',
    listeners : {
                'resize' : function(win,width,height,opt){
                   console.log(width);
                   console.log(height);
                 }
    }
}).show();
```

refer [Ext.window.Window-event-resize](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-resize)